# consume free space of reportviewer body to reduce total number of pages

Tags: .net, printing, reporting

I've two columns report, when exporting or printing the result is multiple pages, each one have table with just two columns and the rest of the page (more than 60% is blank). Is there way to let the reportviewer append the rest of table to the next of existing table in the same page rather than make new page?
as image describe[image: ![two columns two pages report to four columns, one page report]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq0fJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by change the underlying SQL query.
I joined the table with itself like:

```
select n1.number, n1.remarks, n2.number, n2.remarks
from numbers as n1 left join numbers as n2 on n2.id = n1.id + 1
where n1.id % 2 =1
```

this may inspire you to solve your problem!
there are two remarks: 
1) the id values **MUST** began with 1 and be sequential (1,2,3...)
2) I've used **left join** to include the last odd id number -if exists.
   I'll explain: if there are three numbers with ids 1,2 and 3, if you use inner join the third number will not appear in query result!